# Exercise 18 page 180 of Hungerford's book Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

The following is Exercise 18 page 180 of Hungerford's book *Algebra*:

> Let $R$ be a ring without identity. Embed $R$ in a ring $S$ with identity and characteristic zero as in the proof of Theorem III.1.10. Identify $R$ with its image in $S$.
> (a) Show that every element of $S$ may be uniquely expressed in the form
> $r 1_S + n 1_S \ (r \in R, n \in \mathbb{Z})$.
> (b) If $A$ is an $R$-module and $a \in A$, show that there is a unique $R$-module homomorphism $f: S \to A$ such that $f(1_S) = a$. [Hint: Let $f(r 1_S + n 1_S) = ra + na$.]

**My questions:**

Item (a) -  If the identity of $S$ is $1_S=(0,1)$, then how $(r,n) = r 1_S + n 1_S$ can be?

Item (b) It is easy to show that $f$ is an $R$-module homomorphism. But how may it be shown to be a unique one?

Answer (score 1):

> Let $R$ be a ring without identity. Embed $R$ in a ring $S$ with identity and characteristic zero as in the proof of Theorem III.1.10. Identify $R$ with its image in $S$.
>
> (a) Show that every element of $S$ may be uniquely expressed in the form
> $r 1_S + n 1_S \ (r \in R, n \in \mathbb{Z})$.
>
> (b) If $A$ is an $R$-module and $a \in A$, show that there is a unique $R$-module homomorphism $f: S \to A$ such that $f(1_S) = a$. [Hint: Let $f(r 1_S + n 1_S) = ra + na$.]

**Proof**:

**Item (a)**. Using the notation of Theorem III.1.10. Identifying $R$ with its image in $S$ means that for all $r\in R$ we will identify $r$ with $(r,0)$.

Recall that $(0,1) \in S$ is the identity in $S$, that is, $(0,1)=1_S$.

Given any $(r,n) \in S$, we have
$$ (r,n) = (r,0) + (0,n) = (r,0)(0,1) + n(0,1) = r1_S + n1_S $$
where in the last step we used the identification of $(r,0)$ with $r$.

**Item (b)**. First note that, identifying $r$ with $(r,0)$, $S$ becames an R-module (just check definition of R-module).

Now, let us define $f: S \to A$ by, for all $r 1_S + n 1_S \in S$,  $f(r 1_S + n 1_S) = ra + na$. Clearly, $f(1_S)=a$.

It is also easy to see that:

1. for all $r 1_S + n 1_S \in S$ and $r' 1_S + n' 1_S \in S$,
   \begin{align*} 
   f((r 1_S + n 1_S)+(r' 1_S + n' 1_S)) &= f((r+r')1_S + (n+n')1_S) \\
   & = (r+r')a + (n+n')a \\
   &= (r a + n a) +  (r' a + n' a) \\
   &= f(r 1_S + n 1_S ) + f(r' 1_S + n' 1_S)
   \end{align*}
2. for all $r' \in R$ and $r 1_S + n 1_S \in S$,
   $$ f(r'(r 1_S + n 1_S ))= f(r'r1_S + nr'1_S) = r'ra + nr'a = r'(ra+na)= r'f(r 1_S + n 1_S) $$
   So $f$ is an R-module homomorphism.

*Uniqueness*: Let  $g: S \to A$  be any R-module homomorphism such that  $g(1_S)=a$. Then, for all $r 1_S + n 1_S \in S$,
$$ g(r 1_S + n 1_S ) = rg(1_S)+ng(1_S)= ra+na =f(r 1_S + n 1_S )$$
So $g=f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)